# Customising scoring algorithm in elasticsearch with scoring script or building my own Lucene Scorer?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, customization, similarity, scoring

I'm using elasticsearch to do some similarity comparison among process models.
The core similarity algorithm should be specialized for my process models, which means, as my imagined, I should customize the score algorithm in elasticsearch.

As I known, the scoring in ES is based on Lucene score algorithm. Although Lucene's DefaultSimilarity works quite well on most of the cases and one can use other similarities in ES like BM25,DRF, such customizing usually extending the existed Lucene classes or overriding its methods to change or disable some weights in my opinion.

In my case, I'd like to make some specialized math things which should be used as scoring and seems to be different with the base Lucene score algorithm. what confused me is, it seems that there are two options for me, one is, I can configurate custom scoring script in ES, the other one is I should build my own Lucene scorer.

Can anybody give me some advice on which approach I should take? or is there any missunderstanding I have. Since I have not very clear about ES and Lucene, maybe there are some other ways to solve my questions and more suitable in my case.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you mind giving some feedback on the answers that you got for you previous questions? WOule be nice to know if they were usueful...

Comment: Sorry for delayed feedback. I didn't noticed the messages and I have done it now. So about this question I also searched some posts and I have an idea that I could use custom scoring script which seems to be easier. Am I right?